# Why did Bavaria join Prussia/Germany instead of Austria?

Tags: 19th-century, austria, austria-hungary, bavaria

I am curious about why kingdom of Bavaria was assimilated by Prussia instead of Austria-Hungary

If I consider following facts in 1854

- Bavaria is Catholic country (same as majority of Austria-Hungary), Prussia is Protestant
- The royal family of Austria is connected with Bavaria nobles. Moreover in this year Franz Joseph marries Elizabeth of Bavaria
- Bavaria is a strong ally of Austria that proved its loyalty in past decades. Moreover this alliance is oriented mainly against Prussia.
- Bavaria is geographically and economically strongly connected with Austria-Hungary (Alps, Danube river,...)
- Bavarians share similar cultural origins with Austrians and Western Bohemians

then something happened and in 1871 Bavaria joins Germany forever. Why?

Comment: ...and both speak [Bavarian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bavarian_language)

Comment: Austro-Prussian War of 1868 perhaps (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Austro-Prussian_War), in which Austro-Hungary was crushed in seven weeks. (Blitzkrieg without tanks or aircraft, if one can believe it.)

Comment: This verges on speculation/counterfactual analysis which is out of scope.  I think the question would be stronger if it included research into the reasons why Bavaria is German rather than Austrian.

Comment: there was an attempt to 'swap' the Austrian Netherlands for Bavaria sometime pre 1800

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: In which Austria (it didn't become Austria-Hungary until 1867, a year _after_ - and as a direct result of the Austrian defeat in - the Austro-Prussian War, which, BTW, happened in 1866, not 1868) _and Bavaria_ (and Hannover, and Saxony, and Baden, and Württemburg, and Hesse-Darmstadt, etc., etc., etc.) were crushed in seven weeks.  Most of the German states allied with Austria against Prussia; many were annexed outright by Prussia following the war, with the rest of the northern states being subsumed into the North German Confederation the following year; (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) only the four big, southern, overwhelmingly Roman Catholic states (Bavaria, Baden, Württemburg, and Hesse-Darmstadt) remained independent (and even they joined in, although more voluntarily, following the Franco-Prussian War a few years later). Together in victory, together in defeat...

Comment: @Sean Wuerttemburg was overwhelming Catholic???

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Bavaria joined Prussia after the [Franco-Prussian War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franco-Prussian_War).

Prussia had emerged as the state that could defend "German" interests by leading the Germans in the defeat of France. Earlier, Prussia had beaten Austria in the [Seven Weeks War](https://www.britannica.com/event/Seven-Weeks-War) of 1866.

Austria had to settle accounts with Hungary after the 1866 war (after having quashed that country's bid for independence in 1848). So in 1867, she elevated Hungary to a "dual" Austro-Hungarian monarchy, allowing Hungary to administer about half the combined [empire.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Austro-Hungarian_Compromise_of_1867) In so "partnering" with a non-Germanic country (as opposed to say, Bavaria, and letting the Hungarians go their way), Austria signaled that German affairs were of secondary importance to her. That signal was further reinforced when Austria declined to join the Germans (or France for that matter) in the Franco-Prussian War.

Under the circumstances, Prussia appeared to be the "coming" German power. With Austria no longer a viable alternative, it was a case of "let's jump on the bandwagon before it's too late."

Comment: I would argue that the defining momemt was the overwhelming success of Prussia in 1868 - which by coercing the formation of the *Dual Monarchy* resulted in Austro-Hungarian ambitions becoming focused on the Balkans instead of Germany. Anu good answer must account fr Austria' *lack of interest* in German affairs during the 1870 war bwteen Prussia (and its allies) against France.

Comment: @Pieter Geerkens: OK, adopted your excellent suggestion about the Dual Monarchy.